# State is returning new state without touching the state REACT/REDUX

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, lodash

Before I start posting the code I will explain what I want to happen and what is happening.

I have been working with this all day and finally got something to work. The problem is that I have no clue why it works and if it's the best way to do it. 
What I want to happen  is when a User clicks delete on a comment I want the comment to be delete from the current `post` on the back end and from the state on the front end.

**UPDATE:** I did not really add enough to show what I was talking about. When a user clicks the delete button it will fire off this function here:

```
deleteComment(comment) {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    const {user, post, auth} = this.props;

    if(!user) {
      return (<div></div>);
    }

    if(auth) {
      if(user._id === comment.author.id){
        this.props.deleteComments(post, comment._id, () => {
          this.props.history.push(`/posts/${post._id}`);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

which then calls the action:

```
export function deleteComments(post, comment_id, cb) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.delete(`${ROOT_URL}/${post._id}/comments/${comment_id}`)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({
          type: DELETE_COMMENTS,
          payload: comment_id,
          post: post
        });
      })
      .then(() => cb())
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

**What I am wondering:**
Really all the code above works so it is more of a reference than anything. I am wondering why in the reducer when `DELETE_COMMENTS` is caught by the switch case how the current state which is below in the picture is changed to a new state without the comment I deleted. I don't explicitly ever edit the state or change it so how does `return (state);` actually change it here?

To elaborate more my current state looks as so:

[image]

As you can see I have a Post with comments inside of it. The comments are stored inside an array and each of them are objects with text, author.id, author.email, and createdAt values. Now as you can see in the reducer_post when the action is fired off it sends the DELETE_COMMENTS dispatch type off and the state is changed.

For help: `action.payload` is the `comment._id`, and `action.post` is the current post that is being viewed.

```
import {
  GET_ALL_POSTS,
  GET_POST,
  CREATE_POST,
  DELETE_POST,
  UPDATE_POST,
  DELETE_COMMENTS
} from '../actions/types';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_ALL_POSTS:
      return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, '_id');
    break;
    case GET_POST:
      return {...state, [action.payload.data._id]: action.payload.data};
    break;
    case DELETE_POST:
      return _.omit(state, action.payload);
    break;
    case DELETE_COMMENTS:
      let newCommentArray = _.reject(action.post.comments, {'_id': action.payload});
      let newPost = action.post;
      newPost.comments = newCommentArray;
      return (state);
    case UPDATE_POST:
      let updates = {[action.payload.data._id]: action.payload.data};
      return _.merge(...state, updates);
    break;
    default:
      return state;
    break;
  }
}
```

I know the back-end works just fine and this also works just fine. My question is how does it update the state with me just putting `return (state);`. I did not have to do something like `return _.merge(...state, newPost);` or something like that. How is all of this working just fine, and no I did not just copy some tutorial and come on here and ask this just to figure out how someone else did it. At the moment I believe in magic so it would be nice for an explanation.

Also since we are here, is this the best way to do it? Or is there a better more clean way of doing things here.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you saying that the state is being modified in the `default` case?  Or are you dispatching an action when the API response returns?  If so, what action are you dispatching?

Comment: Let me add some edits, I can see where this is confusing sorry.

Comment: Probably because `state` contains a object reference to `comments`, eg `state["postid"].comments === action.post.comments` or something to that effect.

Comment: so changing action.post will change the state ?

Comment: I think that you just dont understand Redux, try reading about it. Every time you change data in your store, the callback from your subscribed component is called, the state changes and component rerenders.

Comment: Don't I have to do something like return (...state, newPost) and merge the current state with the new state I want? Or does directly changing the action.post affect the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're actually directly mutating the state, and somehow getting away with it in the sense that the component is still updating.

Let's follow the trail of logic:

1. In `deleteComment()`, you reference `this.props.post`.  That object is presumably extracted from the store via `mapStateToProps`, so it's the object reference in the store.
2. `post` gets passed to `this.props.deleteComments(post)`
3. `deleteComments()` dispatches `({type : DELETE_COMMENTS, post})`
4. In the reducer, you have `let newPost = action.post; newPost.comments = newCommentArray`.  But, at that point, **`newPost` still points to the exact same object that's already in the store state**.  So, you've directly mutated it.

Normally, this kind of mutation would result in your component not re-rendering, so I can only assume that some other value extracted in `mapState` is also getting updated properly, and thus causing a re-render.

As discussed in the [Structuring Reducers - Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) page in the Redux docs, `let someVariable = anotherVariable` doesn't create a new object reference - it merely creates a second variable that points to the *same* object reference.  Proper immutable updates require copies of *every* level of nesting that you're working with, not just the one level.  In your case, you're creating a new array via `_.reject()`, but you're not creating a copy of the `post` object.

So, in the end, your reducer logic is incorrect, and your application is sorta kinda working by accident :)

**update**

Responding to your question about a proper update: you need to create a *copy* of the `post` object and update it with the new comments array, and you need to copy the `state` object and update it with the new post object.  Based off what the rest of your code does, my guess is this should work:

```
case DELETE_COMMENTS:
     const newCommentArray = _.reject(action.post.comments, {'_id': action.payload});

     const newState = {
         ...state,
         [action.post.id] : {
             ...action.post,
             comments : newCommentArray
         }
     };

     return newState;
```

Comment: How would I do this correctly? If you don't mind answering that so others will know when they see this also.

Comment: I looked at the docs and the nested level of data is very confusing to me.

Comment: Update my answer to demonstrate proper immutable updates.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out, but this makes much more since to me now haha

Comment: So lets say I needed to edit the author that sits on comments. I would have to go another level? So something like 
`const newState = {
         ...state,
         [action.post.id] : {
             ...action.post,
             comments : newCommentArray,
                 ...action.post.comments,
                     author: newAuthor
         }
     };`

Comment: Your snippet looks off, but yes - as I said, you need to make a copy of _every_ level of nesting that needs to be updated, whether it's another object or an array.  So, if you have `state.a.b.c[5].d`, you would need to make copies of the object at `[5]`, the array at `c`, the object at `b`, the object at `a`, and the `state` object, appropriately.  The "Immutable Update Patterns" docs page I linked describes how to do that properly.

Comment: I think the syntax is just a little confusing. Would I just add a comma comments: newCommentArray? They don't really show how to do the syntax after the level where you make a copy of something like the object or array.

Also I just tried to code and what you gave me did not work. It does not make the comment disappear off the page so I'm guessing it's not updating the state correctly?

Comment: Nvm I got it to work I will just look at the docs and if I run into a problem Ill post another question !